# Time difference between fadeIn() delay() and fadeOut()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to calculate the time difference from the moment the command line (3) starts and ends, but looks like I am wrong, as line(7) shows zero. I am expecting it to show 6500 (1500 + 3500 + 1500).
please help me.

```
sd = new Date(); 
sdm = sd.getMilliseconds();
$(imgs).eq(i).fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500);
ed = new Date(); 
edm = ed.getMilliseconds();
df = edm - sdm;
document.getElementById('df').innerHTML = df;
```

The reason I am throwing this question is, I am writing a slideshow (very simple) and it is not showing the images in sequence properly as it jumps from one to another.

This is my HTML and the JS.

```
    $(document).ready(
      function() {

            var i=0;
            var imgs = $('#images ul').children();
            var j = imgs.length;

            setInterval(function(){ runIt(); }, 6500);

            function runIt() {
                i = i + 1;
                if (i == j) { i=0;}

                $(imgs).eq(i).fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500);
            }

    }); 

<div id="slider">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="images/slider/s1.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/slider/s2.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/slider/s3.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/slider/s4.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

thank you.

Comment: Did you read the jQuery documentation for these methods? If not, you should do that first. Also you seem to be asking two different questions here.

Comment: Only one question. The reason I am having the first question is because of the second question. In order to identify the problem in the 2nd question, i wrote the first one.

Comment: I believe reading https://api.jquery.com/fadein/ and https://api.jquery.com/fadeout/ will answer all your questions.

Comment: I did read the above documents but I dont find anything in regard to timing and execution sequence....

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/dLbrh7vy/ . Can provide a better explanation of the issue?

Comment: If you worried about it skipping the first image, do the following: in your `runIt()` function, move `i = i + 1;` to the bottom of that function.

Answer (score 5):

Calls to animating functions in jQuery are asynchronous. You need to use a callback function, like so:

```
$(element).fadeOut(delay,
    function() {
        // callback action
    }
);
```

However, this will not work as expected. getMilliseconds returns the milliseconds that have passed since the beginning of the second, e.g., if the current time is 20:18:20.430, it will return 430. You want to use the method getTime instead. It returns the number of milliseconds since the [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Since you are using jQuery, instead of document.getElementById'ing, you can use the much more concise `$('#id').html('...');`. This leaves us with:

```
sd = new Date(); 
sdm = sd.getTime();
$(imgs).eq(i).fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500,
    function() {
        ed = new Date(); 
        edm = ed.getTime();
        df = edm - sdm;
        $('#df').html(df);
    }
);
```

Your slideshow is probably also messed up because of this.

A small nitpick regarding your second snippet: in `var imgs = $('#images ul').children();`, the `.children()` method returns a jQuery object. You needn't really run it through `$()` again, but you can if you think that's more clear.

```
imgs.eq(i).fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer. It works in IE and Chrome. I did not check in FF.

```
$(document).ready(
  function() {

        var i=0;
        var imgs = $('#images ul').children();
        var j = imgs.length;

        setInterval(function(){ runIt(); }, 5000);

        function runIt() {
            $(imgs).eq(i).fadeOut(1500)
            i = i + 1;
            if (i == j) { i=0;}
            $(imgs).eq(i).fadeIn(1500);
        }

});
```

Thanks for all your comments & suggestions. This way, it wont get stuck or it wont hold an image. 
I looked at Felix Kling's fiddle, the image is disappearing and the next image comes in. I want the next image to blend in.
Thanks again.